# Box and Whisker Plot in tableau to show box for row wise

Tags: tableau-api, powerbi

I have following data.

```
Question1             Question2
agree                disagree
strongly agree       disagree
disagree             disagree
strongly disagree    agree
strongly agree       agree
strongly agree       strongly agree
strongly agree       strongly agree
agree                strongly agree
disagree             strongly disagree
disagree             strongly disagree
```

I want the box and whisker to be plotted as seen in image based on median.

[image]

Do i need to mark 1 to 4 for measurements. 
How do i align columns in table into tableau so that it show's put as seen in image.

If not in tableau can i achieve it in power BI , if so how ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. First, can you format your data like this?

[image]

2. After that, I don't have an great idea for how to change the number values to the text you want on the x-axis. Here's one shot at it. On the x-axis title you could get really experimental with spacing.

[image]